# Why is a diode-connected BJT more "ideal" than a simple pn diode?

Tags: diodes

I have often seen it stated and discussed that a diode-connected BJT has an ideality factor (n) closer to 1 in Shockley's diode equation when compared with a simple pn diode's ~2/3.

Why is this?

Comment: High level injection and sometimes also bulk Ohmic resistance makes the diode less ideal. Diode connected BJTs usually aren't used at those kinds of levels and they are made differently. (Their reverse breakdown is pretty low.) The factor is a "tweak" of sorts that gets modeling them okay over their specified range of use.

Comment: If you want a much more serious answer, I can provide the old papers you can read on a variety of more physically real effects and associated construction details. But it complicates the analysis a lot and the factor suffices for most uses.

Comment: @jonk I'm eventually interested by your "old papers". Do you have references or ideally links ?

Comment: @jonk Thanks for your response. I too would be interested in seeing these papers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diodes come in low-current types, that have a point-contact-like
geometry, for high speed operation.   The depletion region in
such diodes is a hemisphere, not a uniform slab, and that
deviates from the diode equation geometry.   Diodes also come in
high-current types, which often have intentional resistive
layers, in order to prevent  hot spot formation.   The resistive
features are not part of the diode equation either.

Small-signal transistors, however, have a large flat thin base
region (which is the right geometry) and minimal resistance
in the emitter, and low-resistance collector metallization,
so the junctions DO fit the equation, even if not 
specifically designed to do so.  It's accidentally
the better 'ideal diode' because of features frequently
designed into diodes.