# Logarithm circuit using op-amp not working

Tags: diodes, analog-computer, analog-multiplier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUUfxv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to build a circuit on a breadboard which takes in a voltage and calculates its logarithm. I found on YouTube that Vout = -(ideality factor · thermal voltage)·log(Vin/Is·R) where Is is the reverse saturation current and R is the resistance. I am using a 1N4148 diode and an LM741 op-amp.

In the given equation, I do not know the ideality factor and Is. I tried different voltages on the input trying to find Is, but each time it gives a different Is.

I was thinking of using log and antilog circuits to make a voltage multiplier that takes two input voltages V1 and V2 and gives output k·V1·V2 where k is some constant, but since the log circuit is not working as expected.

The LTspice simulation is showing the output properly but, it is not working on the breadboard.

Here is the log circuit I am using (from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Nrfb-s0wl6g?si=POPSO2nVojF6cIMG&t=403)):

[image]

Comment: Diode connected transistors (base and collector connected) follow the Shockley diode equation much more faithfully than actual diodes. Not sure why, but it seems to be empirically true. So try a diode connected transistor.

Comment: Yes I did use that as well. It gave the value of ln2 0.692 which is very accurate. I used a 3.3 mega ohm resistance. But when I gave Vin as 5 it should have given me ln5 but instead it gave me a negative value. Can you please tell me how to find out Is of diode connected transistor?

Comment: What are you using for an op-amp, and what are the rail voltages?

Comment: LM741 for op amp and 12 and -12 for rail voltages. I am making this project for a college competition that has specified that the input voltages should be under 12 and they will give them such that the output will also not exceed 12 V.

Comment: Please show your circuit. The built in schematic editor is amazingly intuitive. Edit question and click component symbols at top of window.  741 is obsolete. You need V+ / V- / Ground. Have you got those?

Comment: I added the circuit I implemented on breadboard. Also, in another stack exchange question the accepted answer said that you can measure the reverse saturation current of 1n4148 by applying -20 V across it and measuring the current but when I tried it out the current was showing 0 uA. My multimeter cannot measure below uA.

Comment: If you plot the result with a range of input values you can see how the result varies from what is expected and whether there is some second order effect infor[orated in the answer. || As input offset voltage varied (and, you can adjust it with a 741) and as input bias current varied, what would you predict the effect on the result would be.

Comment: Measuring a a number of results at differing Vin values and reporting the results  helps us help you. Without this we cannot tell what is happening with your system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be quite a lot of variation in diode ideality, even in diodes from the same batch, so even if you did have an accurate figure for one particular device, it will not necessarily be the same for the other one in your multiplier.

You can reduce the circuit's dependence on diode ideality by employing a diode-connected transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjb6IX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sometimes you see Q1's base connected to ground instead, which is equivalent due to the virtual ground at the op-amp's inverting input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUUytx.png)</sup>

The diode connected transistor behaves much more like an ideal diode. Instead of passing current through the base-emitter junction, which will necessarily cause additional voltage drop across that junction's own resistance, the bulk of that current comes in via the collector, not the base.

If there's a possibility of negative inputs, don't allow the base-emitter junction to become reverse biased beyond 5V or so, since it's a zener diode and will begin to conduct. You can prevent that by providing your op-amp with a 5V positive supply, or you could place another diode in anti-parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffIoIp.png)</sup>

Even with input grounded, op-amp input offset voltage can cause the output to saturate against the positive supply rail. The 741 has the ability to null that offset, and you should use it.

The value of R1 is comparable with the 741's own input resistance, and input bias current will ruin accuracy. Either decrease R1 by orders of magnitude, or use a FET-input op-amp instead.

#### Also (update)

Perhaps your 741 is exhibiting [output phase reversal](https://www.eetimes.com/The-phase-reversal-story/), which can occur if the inputs are exposed to potentials outside their somewhat limited acceptable range. In this respect, and many others, the 741 is a terrible device by modern standards, and this wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: Yes I did try that and it gave me a very accurate result for ln2 but it gave me a negative value for ln5. I used BC547.

Comment: @AryanGupta This is an inverting configuration. You should expect a negative output for positive inputs. And you should expect maximum positive output for all negative inputs, since gain is huge, and the the op-amp is saturated.

Comment: Yeah so for ln2 it gave me a negative output but for ln5 a positive output. Also even if I neglect the sign the value of ln5 it gave me was way off. Should I try using a different transistor?

Comment: The equation I found when using transistor as diode in logarith op amp circuit was :
Vout = -Vt*ln(Vin/Is*R) where Vt is the thermal voltage, Is is the saturation current and R is the resistance connected. In my calculations I was using Vt as 26 mV. Can you please tell me how to find out Is so that I can choose R = 1/Is and make the denominator inside ln(Vin/Is*R) equal to 1?

Comment: @AryanGupta When the transistor's base-emitter junction is reverse biased, beyond 5V or so, it conducts. It's a zener diode. Therefore you should not use a positive op-amp supply over about 6V (remember that the 741 output can't get closer than a couple of volts from the supply rails).

Comment: But in this case since base is grounded and the output, which is always going to be negative in my case (I am providing integer voltages between 1-12), is connected to the emitter doesn't that mean that base emitter will always be forward biased?

Comment: @AryanGupta You are correct, with a caveat: input offset voltage. I've added more notes to my answer, which may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about offset null I will definitely try that. Also you said to reduce R from 3.3 Mega ohm. Should I try 22 Kilo ohm? I was thinking of choosing R such that Is*R equals to 1 but I do not know the value of Is. How do I find it out? In the datasheet or are there experimental methods to find Is?

Comment: @AryanGupta I imagine you can find \$I_S\$ by actually measuring your log-amp's output for some given input. Rearrange the equation to make \$I_S\$ the subject of the formula, and plug in your measured values (don't forget to calculate transition voltage \$V_T\$ accurately too, so you'll need to know ambient temperature). Since the output of your amplifier will be between 0V and -0.7V, you should try to obtain an output somewhere where the slope isn't extreme, well within those bounds

Comment: @AryanGupta I'd be looking for as small an input current as possible, but still orders of magnitude greater than the op-amp's input bias current. A logarithm looks the same at all scales, so your chief concern here is input bias current. \$R_1=22k\$ is much, much better.

Comment: @SimonFitch Do you happen to know why a diode-connected BJT is more "ideal" than a diode, or has less variation?

Comment: @Puk Instead of passing current through the base-emitter junction, which will necessarily cause additional voltage drop across that junction's own resistance, the bulk of that current comes in via the collector, not the base.

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you. That still raises some questions for me. The collector current still passes through the base-emitter junction so I would expect it to still contribute to the voltage across this junction. Further, I'm not sure how a BJT would alleviate the ideality factor \$n\approx 2\$ due to carrier recombination (at low bias) and high-level injection (at high bias), but maybe it just doesn't. I suppose the latter might have to do with the highly-doped emitter. Nonetheless I've found [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473651/225991) that seems to make some sense.

Comment: @Puk Sorry I can't answer better than Jonk did, and I can only speculate that the mechanism for getting carriers from the collector to traverse the base maybe somehow different from the mechanism at work for those entering the base directly via its terminal. It's a mystery to me too. Even though that junction may be nearer to ideal, as Jonk suggests, there must be more to it than that, since otherwise we wouldn't bother joining collector and base!

Comment: @Puk It's bugging me too, now, so I asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/700987/292884).

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you, I'll keep an eye on it. As for why the bulk of the current needs to come from the collector, if the current were being supplied only by the base terminal, I suppose there would be a large series resistance associated with current flowing from the base contact into the narrow base region from its side(s). Moreover, I suspect this would cause non-uniform potential across the width of the base region, causing the area(s) close to the base contact(s) to turn on and conduct more, leading to substantial deviation from ideal behavior. This is mostly conjecture on my part.

Answer (score 5):

> I did try that and it gave me a very accurate result for ln2 but it gave me a negative value for ln5. I used BC547.

When sizing the resistor and diode (diode connected transistor) it is important to remember this fact. A diode will never have more than, say 800 mV across it unless the current through it is very large. But, an op-amp cannot supply a very large current, and a diode connected transistor will probably overheat if it has a very large current. So in practice, we must find the maximum current we feel comfortable with.

The [datasheet for the LM741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) says that this device has a typical output short-circuit current of 25 mA.

To be conservative, lets say you want the maximum feedback current in your log amplifier to be 10 mA.

The [BC547 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/BC550_D-2310266.pdf) has the following chart for \$V_{BE}\$ vs \$I_C\$

[image]

It appears that a 10 mA current through a diode connected BC547 will result in a voltage drop of somewhere in the vicinity of 720 mV.

Now suppose you want your log amplifier to accept a 9V input. When the input is 9V, that 9V will drop across the input resistor, because the inverting input pin of the op-amp is at virtual ground. If 10 mA flows through the resistor (to match the 10 mA through the BC547), the resistance should be 9/0.01 = 900 \$\Omega\$.

If 9V gives a 720 mV output, you will want to find the constant k such that

$$k = \frac{0.72}{\text{ln} ~ 9} \approx 0.3277$$

Your transfer function will then be

$$ V_{out} = -k \cdot \text{ln} ~ V_{in}$$

(Note that because the amplifier is in inverting configuration, you will get a negative output for a positive input.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK6Khw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is one design, but if you wish to change the design parameters, I have laid out the basic factors you must consider.

Incidentally, since your output is restricted to less than 1 V, you may use substantially lower power rails for your op-amp, if you want. You may also use an op-amp which uses lower voltage power rails but permits a larger output current. But these changes are not necessary but optional.

Note also that CircuitLab does not seem to use a Shockley diode equation for either diodes or for the base-emitter junction of a transistor. Rather they seem to have a "cutoff voltage", below which no current flows. Use another simulator if you want to get true logarithmic behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll go try it out and see if it works. I made two logarithm circuits, one which takes the Vin I want to calculate and one which calculates logarithm of 1. This was when I subtract their output I can eliminate the Is*R term. It was giving accurate result for upto Vin = 5V but more than that it was pretty inaccurate.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy, Interesting... I hadn't noticed that this circuit just wastes most of the supply power.  This is why it is not good practice to work with "ideal" op-amps without power pins.

Answer (score 5):

## When the circuit does not work

There is a paradox in circuitry that perhaps applies to everything in life - *for the purposes of understanding, it is better that the circuit does not start working after you make it and turn on the power*.  Because if it starts working right away, you will not think about it, but if it does not work, you are forced to do it. That is why I have always told my students in the lab, "Be glad your circuit did not work and be sorry when it did" :-)

## Looking for the idea

There have been quite a few circuit solutions of a log converter (with diodes, transistors and op-amps) and this makes us think of somehow arranging them. The most logical way is to start from the simplest and reach the most complex schematic solution; thus, by following the evolution of the circuit idea, we will understand it best.

There are a bunch of interesting questions here that we need to answer: "Why is only a diode not enough to make a log converter? Why do we add a resistor first and then an op-amp? Why we replace the diode with a transistor? And how is it that with just a simple connection between the base and the collector, the transistor is transformed so that it starts converting current to voltage instead of voltage to current as usual? Does the op-amp from the last circuit (with the so-called "transdiode") have anything to do with this? Why are the op-amp implementations inverting?"

## Diode log converters

To make a functional (log) converter, we need a device with a corresponding functional relationship between its input and output magnitude. Fortunately, the IV curve of a PN junction is close to logarithmic...

### I-to-V log converter

... so the first thought that comes to mind is to use a diode as a *log current-to-voltage converter*. This means that we have to pass a current through the diode as an input quantity and take the voltage drop across the diode as an output quantity.

**Unloaded:** Let's first connect a (perfect) voltmeter as a "load" (open circuit or simply put, "nothing") and begin to change the current within wide limits. We notice that the voltage across the diode changes very little, which corresponds to our intuitive idea about this element. The reason is that the diode behaves like a "dynamic resistor" that decreases its resistance when the current increases and vice versa, increases its resistance when the current decreases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRK8En.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we sweep (change) the input current from zero to 1 mA by the help of the CircuitLab *DC Sweep Simulation*, we will see that the output voltage changes logarithmically.

[image: STEP 1.1.1]

**Loaded:** Now let's load this passive circuit with say 1 kΩ load (for this purpose, we can just set such resistance on the voltmeter in its *parameters* field). The load diverts a current through itself, the equivalent resistance decreases, and we see that the voltage drops by about 40 mV...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fogCnO.png)</sup>

... and the curve changes its shape. Therefore, the load degrades the shape of the curve.

[image: STEP 1.1.2]

**Buffered:** The straightforward solution is to buffer the output with a voltage follower. It now copies the diode voltage across the load by supplying it with current from its own supply rather than the input source. The result is obvious - the voltage returns to its initial value (without load, Schematic 1.1.1)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsCFMx.png)</sup>

... and the curve takes its initial shape as in the graph to Schematic 1.1.1.

[image: STEP 1.1.3]

### V-to-V log converter

**Unloaded:** However, we want the drive circuit not by current but by voltage. For this purpose, we connect in series with the input voltage source a resistor acting as a *voltage-to-current converter*. We know that the resistor is supposed to be a linear converter...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv1Nl2.png)</sup>

... but we see that the circuit performs poorly at 1 V input voltage.

[image: STEP 1.2.1.1]

**Vin = 10 V:** Aha... see, the voltage across the resistor (the difference between the input and output voltages) is small. If we increase the input voltage to say 10 V...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC6q4n.png)</sup>

... things get better.

[image: STEP 1.2.1.2]

**Loaded:** As above, the load distorts the shape of the curve...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHcmmN.png)</sup>

... especially if the input voltage is low (1 V).

[image: STEP 1.2.2]

Therefore, the simple passive circuit has two major problems - *input* (low input voltage) and *output* (low-resistance load). And here we wonder if there is no remedy to solve both problems?

**Voltage-source compensated:** It turns out that there is, and it is very well known to us from life - *we compensate for the voltage loss VF across the diode by adding a voltage of the same value*. For this purpose, we connect a following ("behavioral") voltage source Vout = VF in series and use its voltage as output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlniz.png)</sup>

The results of this simple action are amazing - the input voltage and the load resistance can be as low as we want because there is no VF and the load is supplied by another voltage source. Note that the output voltage is negative in respect to ground (the curve is below zero) but is added to Vin when travelling the loop.

[image: STEP 1.2.3]

**Op-amp compensated:** In practical circuits, an op-amp can serve as the compensating voltage source Vout. By the help of the negative feedback principle, it compares its output voltage Vout with the diode voltage VF and makes the difference between them (almost) equal to zero (the so-called *virtual ground*). As a result, Vout = VF.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQneOJ.png)</sup>

The curve is the same as above and below zero.

[image: STEP 1.2.4]

## Transistor-diode log converters

A tempting idea is to make a log converter with a transistor instead of a diode. Transistors are active devices and also have such but an inverse (exponential) functional relationship between the input (Vbe) and output (Ic) quantity... and for some reason it is better. So it would be great if we could "reverse"  them so that they convert current to voltage instead of voltage to current. For example, if some people are born bad but we force them to do good deeds, they become good; if we are too considerate of our subordinates, they are effectively ruling us, etc. The name of this trick is *negative feedback*.

**Unloaded:** So, if we connect the transistor base to its collector, it will adjust its Vbe so that to pass the input current Vin/R through its base-emitter part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTkEce.png)</sup>

Thus the transistor is "reversed"  and its transfer curve is the same as of the diode IV curve.

[image: STEP 2.1]

**Loaded:** The collector-emitter section connected in parallel to the base-emitter junction acts as a "shunt booster".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLXIrp.png)</sup>

So the curve is good even if a load is connected.

[image: STEP 2.2]

### Op-amp transistor diode

The "harmful" collector-emitter voltage can be neutralized by an op-amp like in the Schematic 1.2.4 above.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGALuq.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2.3]

## Transdiode log converters

And finally, the transistor can be controlled by the op-amp from the side of the emitter (like in the common-base configuration). The op-amp adjusts its Vout so that to pass the input current Vin/R through the transistor base-emitter part. An additional advantage is that the base current does not flow through the input voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGHFmv.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3.1]

"Trans-" comes from the fact that unlike a regular diode where the voltage and current appear between two same points (cathode and anode), here they appear in different places (base-emitter and collector-emitter).

Comment: "we will see that the output voltage changes logarithmically." Except that it doesn't because, as we both know, CircuitLab didn't implement the Vbe relationship logarithmically. There was another question where this came up, and I can find it if you would like, but I recall seeing ridiculously high Vbe's because of the non-logarithmic Vbe formula.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy,  That's right, but what can I do, I just hoped you wouldn't notice -:) I tried connecting a diode in parallel to the base-emitter junction, but it didn't work. Still, that shouldn't stop us from revealing the ideas of these famous circuits, right?

Comment: :-)............

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simulation with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110) of this circuit with temperature variable (T°=0, 27, 50 °C).
Correction of "offset" applied, opamp is an LF13741, +/- 15 V power supplied.

[image]